# How to create a desktop or plank shortcut for Musique (Flavio Tordini app)?

Tags: music

I had a problem installing [Musique](https://flavio.tordini.org/musique) in Elmentary OS 5.1. Finally the only way I could execute the app is typing the following commands on a terminal `source /opt/qt512/bin/qt512-env.sh && musique`

The musique app on the slingshot do not start. My question is how to create a desktop shorcut for the custom terminal command `source /opt/qt512/bin/qt512-env.sh && musique` and add this shorcut to the Elementary slingshot?

I have tried so many things with Appeditor and editing the .desktop file of Musique but nothing worked. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Open AppEditor and make a new entry.

```
sh -c "source /opt/qt512/bin/qt512-env.sh && musique"
```